# Scala multiline regex / regular expression (?m) not working

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, multiline

(all of the example can be run through scala repl or sbt console)

I have this multiline string:

```
val a= "A0DA000043\n"+
"A020000008933F57845F706921\n"+
"A0A0000000 (9000)\n"+
"A0A40000027FDE (9FXX,9000) \n"+
"84E400000BD2012F261C86BC6C3C679F (6101,9000)\n"+
"00A4040008A000000151000000 (61XX,9000)"
```

Then I have this regular expression:

```
(?m)^ *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *$
```

I use it like this:

```
scala> """(?m)^ *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *$""".r.pattern.matcher(a).matches()
res10: Boolean = false
```

but if do this:

```
scala> ("""(?m)^ *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *$""".r findAllIn a).toList
res8: List[String] = List(A0DA000043, A020000008933F57845F706921, A0A0000000 (9000), "A0A40000027FDE (9FXX,9000) ", 84E400000BD2012F261C86BC6C3C679F (6101,9000), 00A4040008A000000151000000 (61XX,9000))
```

it returns all the lines. But I wonder why .matches() is not working.

If i try a single line in .matches

```
scala> """(?m)^ *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *$""".r.pattern.matcher("A0A40000027FDE (9FXX,9000)").matches()
res9: Boolean = true
```

Now even the simplest multi line regex is not working

```
"(?m)^foo$".r.pattern.matcher("foo\nfoo").matches()
res38: Boolean = false
```

what is wrong? can anybody give an example on how to use (?m) or even try to match the val a.

I want to know if val a lines matches my regex.

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT:** I tried some of the answer below, like use (?s) and .* for my newline. It worked for example 1 but it is considering the **invalid data as valid**. Ex:

```
scala> val c = "A0A0000000 (9000"
c: String = A0A0000000 (9000

scala> """(?s)^ *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *.*$""".r.pattern.matcher(c).matches()
res45: Boolean = true
```

Comment: `.*` at the last will match all the remaining not-allowed chars greedily.

Answer (score 0):

Because `matches` tries to match the whole string. `"(?m)^foo$"` regex won't match the newline character and the following `foo` string present in the input string `foo\nfoo`.

The below code will return `True`, because the regex used, will match the whole string.

```
"(?s)^foo.*$".r.pattern.matcher("foo\nfoo").matches()
```

Comment: could you do it in my example string too? I tried """(?s)^ *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *.*$""".r.pattern.matcher(a).matches() base on your comment. And it work but. this: "A0A0000000 (9000" is still considered valid even though it is not

Comment: that's a completely different thing try `(?s)^(?: *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *\n?)+$` in `matches` method.

Comment: Hi thanks, it worked.. But I am getting stackoverflow (in my application)/ scala repl hangs when the string is too long . example :  """(?s)^(?: *(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+(?: +\([0-9A-FX,]+\))? *\n?)+$""".r.pattern.matcher("A0DC0504448001019000800102A4083010A95010880011C9700FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9000)").matches()

Comment: I think it is because of this {2} <-  I need it to be in pairs because it should be a valid hexbinary